# ¿Cómo añadir un buscador de páginas a un iframe con un PDF de múltiples hojas?

Tags: html, iframe

tengo una consulta. tengo un iframe que contiene un pdf que va variando conforme selecciono los diferentes enlaces que llevan a otros pdf. Algunos de ellos tienen bastantes hojas, por lo que me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poner una especie de buscador donde pueda buscar una pagina del pdf directamente para cambiar de hoja, y no tener que hacer scroll en el pdf.
Os adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #fefae0;
    font-family: arial;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#tabla {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}

#pdf-iframe {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#imagen {
    width: 25%;
}

.titulo {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
<title>1</title>

</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla">
    <tr height="5%">
        <td colspan="2"><img id="imagen" src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/></td>
        <td rowspan="10" colspan="1" width="92%"><iframe id="pdf-iframe" src="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" name="cuadro" scrolling="no"></iframe></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="zona1"><a href="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p  class="titulo">PAGINA 1</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 1</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 2</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion3.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 3</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 4</p></td>
        
        <td class="zona2"><a href="pagina2/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p  class="titulo">PAGINA 2</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 1</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 2</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion3.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 3</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 4</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si haces `pagina1/opcion1.pdf#page=N`, según la [documentación](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html), debería cargar la página que deseas.

Comment: Hola, esa opción me sirve para abrir directamente por una página específica. Pero lo que me gustaría lograr es que el usuario pueda ir a una página u otra de forma que él lo elija @Alfabravo

Comment: Entonces usa algo como pdf.js de los amigos de Mozilla https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

Comment: vale, voy a buscar como hacerlo. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Un pdf embebido, por defecto genera un toolbar con diferentes herramientas como búsqueda y zoom, lo cual veo que necesitas en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584935/agregar-un-bot%c3%b3n-para-restablecer-el-tama%c3%b1o-del-pdf-dentro-de-un-iframe-en-una-p). Hay alguna razón para que ocultes el toolbar en la URL? `pagina2/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0`