# agregar un botón para restablecer el tamaño del PDF dentro de un iframe en una página web

Tags: html, iframe, zoom

tengo una consulta. La página web que estoy haciendo contiene un iframe, y el iframe contiene un pdf que varía cuando pulso alguno de los enlaces que llevan a otros pdf. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de implementar que si hago zoom en uno de los pdf, pulsando un botón pueda reestablecer el tamaño del pdf de forma que se ajuste a las dimensiones del iframe (que se haga más pequeño). Entiendo que debería establecer de alguna forma el tamaño del pdf para que vuelva después a su tamaño original, pero no sé como. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #fefae0;
    font-family: arial;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#tabla {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}

#pdf-iframe {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#imagen {
    width: 25%;
}

.titulo {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.zona1 {
    background-color: #219ebc;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.zona2 {
    background-color: #8ecae6;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
 color: black;
}

a:visited {
 color: black;
}

a:focus {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
<title>1</title>

</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla">
    <tr height="5%">
        <td colspan="2"><img id="imagen" src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/></td>
        <td rowspan="10" colspan="1" width="92%"><iframe id="pdf-iframe" src="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" name="cuadro" scrolling="no"></iframe></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="zona1"><a href="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p  class="titulo">PAGINA 1</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 1</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 2</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion3.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 3</p>
        <a href="pagina1/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 4</p></td>
        
        <td class="zona2"><a href="pagina2/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p  class="titulo">PAGINA 2</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 1</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 2</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion3.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 3</p>
        <a href="pagina2/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" target="cuadro"><p>OPCIÓN 4</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Un pdf embebido, por defecto genera un toolbar con diferentes herramientas como búsqueda y zoom, lo cual veo que necesitas en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584930/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1adir-un-buscador-de-p%c3%a1ginas-a-un-iframe-con-un-pdf-de-m%c3%baltiples-hojas). Hay alguna razón para que ocultes el toolbar en la URL? `pagina2/opcion4.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0`

Comment: esa toolbar me genera también agregar texto y hacer modificaciones sobre el pdf, y no quiero que se pueda hacer eso. Algunas de las opciones del toolbar si que me sirven pero no quiero que aparezcan las otras. @DjCrazy